An index error occurs while testing parameters in my cost function
Here is the error: IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6
I have not done anything since I don't know how to fix the problem. My cost function gets an expected output using another test for w,b parameters but for this test, the output is correct but has an index error.
Code
for i in range(m):
    z_wb = 0
    for j in range(n):
        # Your code here to calculate w[j] * X[i][j] z_wb += z_wb_ij # equivalent to z_wb = z_wb + z_wb_ij z_wb+=b –
        z_wb_ij = w[j] * X[i][j]

# Calls the compute_cost function that you implemented above
---> 18     cost_without_reg = compute_cost(X, y, w, b)
     19 
     20     print(f'cost without reg is:{cost_without_reg}')

<ipython-input-17-d111fe703811> in compute_cost(X, y, w, b, *argv)
     32         for j in range(n):
     33             # Add the corresponding term to z_wb
---> 34             z_wb_ij = w[j]*X[i][j]                  # Your code here to calculate w[j] * X[i][j]
     35             z_wb += z_wb_ij                         # equivalent to z_wb = z_wb + z_wb_ij
     36 


IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6
"n" has a value of 2 in a matrix of 100 rows (m) and 2 columns (n)

Can you add minimal code, inputs and expected outputs?

for i in range(m):
z_wb=0
    for j in range(n): 
        
        z_wb_ij = w[j]*X[i][j]                  # Your code here to calculate w[j] * X[i][j]
        z_wb += z_wb_ij                         # equivalent to z_wb = z_wb + z_wb_ij
    z_wb+=b


m is 100 and n is 2? It's simple. Print out len(X), len(X[0]), len(w), and len(w[j]) and see which one are not in the bound.  Edit your question and post your code, inputs and expected outputs? Otherwise, we can't help you, I'm afraid.

print(len(X))            100
print(len(X[0]))         2
print(len(w))             2
print(len(w[j]))      has no length

Try this?:

I believe you are writing code for a linear regression. I am doing logistic regression so my  remaining code calculates "loss" for logistic regression. So, it seems like there are enough indexed items in the matrix for the test to access so I don't understand why the index error is coming up even though the output comes out as expected (0.218).
